# How to append draggable into new droppable area?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have 3 different jQuery droppables.

```
$(".pages").droppable({
        accept: ".draggable"
});
```

```
<div id="droppable1" class="droppable" style="height: 300px; width: 300px;"></div>
<div id="droppable2" class="droppable" style="height: 300px; width: 300px;"></div>
<div id="droppable3" class="droppable" style="height: 300px; width: 300px;"></div>
```

I have one jQuery draggable that I'm using clone with

```
 $(".draggable").draggable({
        helper:'clone'
    });
```

```
<div id="draggable" class="drag-box ui-widget-content">
    <p>Drag Me</p>
  </div>
```

If I move my draggable into droppable 1, I need to be able to attach/append the clone it creates inside droppable 1 so that it reads..

```
<div id="droppable1" class="droppable" style="height: 300px; width: 300px;">
<div id="draggable" class="drag-box ui-widget-content">
    <p>Drag Me</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, if I were to move it from droppable1 containment area into droppable2's then it would move it under droppable2, without actually deleting the element of course, to read like...

```
<div id="droppable1" class="droppable" style="height: 300px; width: 300px;">
</div>

<div id="droppable2" class="droppable" style="height: 300px; width: 300px;">
<div id="draggable" class="drag-box ui-widget-content">
    <p>Drag Me</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example, I hope it's what you wanted.

If you want to check (once dropped) if the element was dropped completely inside the container, you can use my answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38806326/jquery-event-for-breaking-draggable-containment/38816518#38816518). Note the the `droppable` element is `this` (inside the `drop` callback function)

```js
function setDraggable(el, doClone) {
  el.draggable({
    helper: doClone ? 'clone' : 'original',
    revert: true
  });
}
$(".droppable").droppable({
  accept: ".draggable",
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    cloned = ui.helper.clone().css({'position': '', 'top': '', 'left': ''});
    setDraggable(cloned, false)
    
    $( this )
    .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
    .append(cloned)
    ui.helper.hide();
  }
});
setDraggable($(".draggable"), true);
```

```css
.droppable {
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.draggable {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
}
.draggable p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div id="droppable1" class="droppable" style="height: 150px; width: 150px;"></div>
<div id="droppable2" class="droppable" style="height: 150px; width: 150px;"></div>
<div id="droppable3" class="droppable" style="height: 150px; width: 150px;"></div>

<br style="clear: both" />
<br />

<div class="draggable">
  <p>Drag Me</p>
</div>
```

> In the example I only hide the original dragged element If you want to remove it completely from the DOM tree you can change `ui.helper.hide();` to `ui.helper.remove();`

Comment: I am wanting to be able to drag the item from 1 droppable area to the next basically.  So once I do the "DRAG ME" toe the first box, I should be able to move it from the first box to the box on the right of it, and vise versa.

Comment: I extremely appreciate your help on this.  The only last thing I don't know how to do is when its moved (as mentioned in original post) that it will actually show up under the <div > that it was moved to.  For example right now if I drag it to the 3rd box.  in HTML its now listed inside the <div id="droppable3"> but if i move it to the dropple2 its still listed inside the droppable3 when inspected.  Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Just use `ui.helper.remove();` instead of `ui.helper.hide();`

Comment: That is awesome man!  Please update answer and I'll mark as accepted.  You have no idea how many hours I've spent researching and trying this on my own.  I had no idea about some of the parts you did under draggable.  Apparently I need to read up on a lot more.  Thanks a ton!

Comment: I added an explanation at the end of the answer regarding the `hide` vs `remove`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121879/discussion-between-dekel-and-eqiz).